# How to Map MSAs in R

Tags: r, maps, census

The question effectively says it all. I have a dataset that is geographically linked to (2019) Metropolitan Statistical Areas and the GEOIDs of each. I want to draw a map of the U.S. that visualizes the range of values across MSAs for a set of variables.

The problem is, while I've done rudimentary mapping on counties and states in Python, I've never done any mapping in R - and I've never used the MSA as the basic geographic unit. To my surprise, resources online seem scarce.

Does anyone have any experience or access to a guide for this? I wouldn't think it'd be that difficult, but I'm no closer to where I started a week ago.

Comment: The `sf` and `ggplot2` packages will handle what you want to achieve. Check out [Drawing beautiful maps programmatically with R, sf and ggplot2](https://r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html) for more information.